# App Script to Find New or Unique Data Between Two Google Spreadsheets (how to append)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've modified the script from the *Removing Duplicate Rows in a Spreadsheet* Google Apps tutorial so that it's comparing data in a given range between two sheets (SRC and DEST). The unique data are then written to the DEST sheet. It seems to work, however the new (unique) data found on the SRC is overwriting the current data on DEST sheet (starting at the first row) and I need it to be appended at the end. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Here's the [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BpYsRkYisHF2IMAbc6MZOZyl6oVsPp4Tc_NmdQExUXE/edit#gid=0)

And here's the script:

```
function appendNEW() {
  // source spreadsheets
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SRC");  
  //destination spreadsheet
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DEST");

  var srcData = srcSheet.getRange('A2:B').getValues();
  var destdData = destSheet.getRange('A2:B').getValues();

  var newData = new Array();


  for(i in srcData){
    var row = srcData[i];
    var duplicate = false;

    for(j in srcData){

        if(row[0] == destdData[j][0] && row[1] == destdData[j][1]){
  duplicate = true;

      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  destSheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

`destSheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);`

try

`destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);`

The above because `destSheet.getLastRow()+1` returns the row number of the first blank row.

Comment: If you want to use [``getNumRows()``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumrows), this is the method of Class Range. And when the default sheet is used, the value of ``getNumRows()`` is 999 for "A2:B". So I thought that you might have mistaken this as ``getLastRow()``.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks. I edited my question to replace `getNumRows()` by `getLastRow()`

Comment: That works, thanks Ruben and Tanaike. Just curious...What about the appendRow() operation? Would that not be appropriate in this case?

Comment: @firenemus appendRow adds a single row. Using it could lead to slower performance.

Comment: @firenemus `appendRow` is useful in cases where you have a volatile spreadsheet, and can't trust that new data hasn't come in since you last called `getLastRow()`. In other words, `appendRow` is "atomic" - effectively standalone and not really dependent on what else is happening to the sheet. `getRange()` + `setValues()` make no guarantee that you haven't filled in that targeted range from a separate script instance. `LockService` offers some assurances for the `setValues` approach.

Comment: This doesn't work if validation is applied because getLastRow() includes validations in cells with values.

Comment: @JanineWhite by blank row I meant a row not included in the data range. A row having data validations, even all the cells in that row are "empty", is included in the data range.